# New DispatcherTimer gets created alongside old one, only new one should run

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, timer, dispatchertimer

I ran into a problem the other day. I have found out why it's happening, but I've never had a run in with such a problem so I don't know how to solve it.

I have an application where in the DashboardView (the main view) a DispatcherTimer is started in the DashboardViewModel. When the Timer ticks, we get the data from the database, this list is databound between the View and the ViewModel. When there is new data that caused the database to change, a sound will play.

The user can go to other Views. When the user goes back to the DashboardView, the DashboardViewModel is again created and so is the DispatcherTimer.
Now there are 2 Timers and they both fire the Tick event, creating a confusing scenario for the user.

**This is my observation of what happens in the application right now:**
My Timer ticks every minute. When I start the application, DashboardView #1 opens. DashboardViewModel #1 starts and so does DispatcherTimer #1.
I switch to a different view, and make an update to the data (a new email) so when the Timer ticks, the list in the DashboardView will change and a sound is played.
When Timer #1 is at 30 seconds, I switch to the DashboardView, which is newly created thus creating View&ViewModel&Timer #2.
After 1 minute, Timer #1 ticks, there is new data so it updates the DB and plays a sound, yet the list in the View doesn't update. 
I think that this is because View #2 is showing over #1. I know because otherwise I would see an overlay saying it's refreshing.
View #2 is databound to ViewModel #2. Timer #1 updated ViewModel #1, so the changes won't show as we can't see View #1 as it's replaced/overlapped by View #2.
After 1 min 30 seconds, Timer #2 ticks, gets the data from the DB, doesn't play a sound as the DB was already brought up-to-date by Timer #1, and shows the data in the new state.
(I hope that made sense)

**So, TLDR: There are 2 Timers running while only 1 should be active (the newest one, I think).
How can I achieve this?**

Here's (part of) the DashboardViewModel as I have it now:

```
namespace QRM.ViewModel
{
    class DashboardListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        DBServer dbServer = new DBServer();

        #region Constructor
        public DashboardListViewModel()
        {
            log.Info("Dashboard Initializing - Starting...");
            MyObservableCollection<View_server> listDashboard = new MyObservableCollection<View_server>();
            ListDashboard = dbServer.ReadDashboard();
            listBoxCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SelectionHasChanged());

            // Refresh to get all new emails, errors, etc.
            GetListDashboard();

            IsRefreshing = Visibility.Collapsed;

            // Make a timer to renew the data in the Dashboard automatically. 
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = Properties.Settings.Default.Timer_interval; // hours, minutes, seconds.
            timer.Start();

            //Receive the Notification sent after DashboardDetailsViewModel has handled the button commands, and call a respond method for the List.
            App.Messenger.Register("RefreshServers", (Action)(() => GetListDashboard()));
            App.Messenger.Register("ClearSelection", (Action)(() => SelectedServer = null));
            App.Messenger.Register("ErrorSolved", (Action)(() => KeepSelection(selectedServer)));
            App.Messenger.Register("WarningSound", (Action)(() => HasNewError = true));
            log.Info("Dashboard Initializing - Done.");
        }
        #endregion

        #region Get list dashboard
        private void GetListDashboard()
        {
            HasNewError = false;
            log.Info("Dashboard - Checking for Email...");

            // The old Outlook class and methods
            //EmailManager checkMail = new EmailManager();
            //checkMail.GetEmail();

            // First, check for mail.
            IMAPManager checkMail = new IMAPManager();
            checkMail.GetEmail();

            log.Info("Dashboard - Checking for linked Errors...");
            // Check if the emails have Errors linked to them. If not, add the Error from the Email to the DB
            ErrorManager checkError = new ErrorManager();
            checkError.GetNewErrors();

            log.Info("Dashboard List - Starting...");
            // Load the dashboard.
            ListDashboard = dbServer.ReadDashboard();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("REFRESHED THE DASHBOARD");
            log.Info("Dashboard List - Done.");
        }

        private void KeepSelection(View_server keepSelection)
        {
            GetListDashboard();
            SelectedServer = keepSelection;
            SelectionHasChanged();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Timer
        //This method runs every time the timer ticks.
        private async void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log.Info("Dashboard - Refreshing...");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(">>Timer tick");
            IsRefreshing = Visibility.Visible;

            // To make sure the overlay is visible to the user, let it be on screen for at least a second (2x half a second)
            await Task.Delay(500);

            if (selectedServer != null)
            {
                KeepSelection(selectedServer);
            }
            else
            {
                GetListDashboard();
            }

            // 2nd half second.
            await Task.Delay(500);
            IsRefreshing = Visibility.Collapsed;

            if (hasNewError == true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("List has new error");
                PlayWarningSound();
                HasNewError = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("List has no new error");
                HasNewError = false;
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(">>End timer");

            log.Info("Dashboard - Refreshed.");
        }        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: "When the user goes back to the DashboardView, the DashboardViewModel is again created". Don't do that. Instead reuse the existing view model instance. Alternatively, if you can't get around creating a new view model instance, make sure to stop the timer in the previous instance, e.g. by implementing `IDisposable`, and of course calling its `Dispose()` method, where you stop the timer.

Comment: Ah. Yeah the view-switching is something I've gotten from another source, so I will have to look into that code to see where the View(Model) is created and/or switched and how. But I think I'll be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues going on here. Let's start with the most basic first:

**Cleanup**

When the `DashboardListViewModel` is disposed of or closed, you need to unwire your `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event handler, invoke `.Stop()` and then call `.Finalize()`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx). This will ensure that your `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` is properly cleaned up.

**Async / Await & Event Handlers**

Also, the `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event handler is defined as `async void`. This is the incorrect usage of the `async` keyword. Instead use this:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.Info("Dashboard - Refreshing...");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(">>Timer tick");
    IsRefreshing = Visibility.Visible;

    // To make sure the overlay is visible to the user, let it be on screen for at least a second (2x half a second)
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    if (selectedServer != null)
    {
        KeepSelection(selectedServer);
    }
    else
    {
        GetListDashboard();
    }

    // 2nd half second.
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    IsRefreshing = Visibility.Collapsed;

    if (hasNewError == true)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("List has new error");
        PlayWarningSound();
        HasNewError = false;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("List has no new error");
        HasNewError = false;
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(">>End timer");

    log.Info("Dashboard - Refreshed.");
}
```

I usually never advise using `Thread.Sleep` but since you're already in the context of a Threading Timer this makes sense.

**One last concern**

Are you certain that the `App.Messenger.Register` can be invoked multiple times, as it occurs every time your view model is instantiated? I would have imagined this would be something you'd only ever want to do once, in `static` context.